# How can I create and move a virtual mouse with python?

Tags: python, controller, mouse

I tried pynput, pyautogui and some other modules, everything works perfectly in windows and fortnite's gui, but when I start a game doesn't rotate. I want to use an 'usb xbox 360 pc controller' (actually just a sixaxis controller) to play fortnite. controllers's driver uses directx 7, windows 10 doesn't support this,
but pygame detects it.

After that I want to make a controller for the game with arduino and sensors!

Comment: what about this? https://joytokey.net/en/

Answer (score 0):

None of this libraries are made to work with games. As explained in this post https://www.learncodebygaming.com/blog/pyautogui-not-working-use-directinput, some games like Minecraft or Fortnite have their own way of registering mouse / keyboard events. The way to fix this, and actually be able to control mouse input and keyboard events is by using the **brand new** PyDirectInput library. Their github repository is https://github.com/learncodebygaming/pydirectinput, and has a lot of great information.
Here's a quick code that does a mouse loop, and clicks:

```py
import pydirectinput  # pip install pydirectinput


pydirectinput.moveTo(0, 500)
pydirectinput.click()
```